# Loading Contacts in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have searched the internet and SO, couldnt find a suitable answer and hence am posting the following.

I want to load the contacts from my Phone into my apps to i can import the phone numbers. What i would wanna do.

1. "Stacy C" has two mobile numbers to her name
2. "Stacy Jacob" has one mobile number

Now when i list the contacts i want three rows with the name and the  number listed below it.
I am able to import the contacts but not sure how to check if the contact has multiple numbers against their name.

Its something similar to WhatsApp Application.
I am using a Cursor with easy loading to list the contacts right now.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser here http://pastebin.com/cDmNNWpY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query another uri for all numbers. I am giving you an example.. you can look into

```
private static final String[] CONTACTS_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    };

    private static final String[] PHONES_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Phone.TYPE,
            Phone.NUMBER
    };

    private void readAllContact() {
        Cursor mCursor = mResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
            // Query phone numbers for this contact.
            if (Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                ArrayList<String> numbers = getPhoneNumbers(id);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No phones associated with this Contact");
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getPhoneNumbers(String id) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor mCursorPhones = mResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PHONES_PROJECTION,
                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id},
                null);
        while (mCursorPhones.moveToNext()) {
            //Read type of phone
            //mCursorPhones.getString(mCursorPhones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            //Read Phone
            result.add(mCursorPhones.getString(mCursorPhones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        }
        mCursorPhones.close();
        return  result;
    }
```

*And for showing rows as many numbers are, yo have to implement your own logic. You can create entries depends on number.*